# find the maclaurin series ln(1+x) by integrating the maclaurin series of its derivative

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Okay so the derivative of $F(x) = \ln (1+x) $ is $ f(x) = 1/x $ $ \forall x \neq 0 $.

To calculate the maclaurin series we need the derivatives of $f(x)$:

$f^{(1)} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$

$f^{(2)} = \frac{2}{x^3}$

$f^{(3)} = -\frac{6}{x^4}$

.
.

$f^{(n)} = (-1)^n \cdot \frac{n!}{x^{n+1}}$.

The maclaurin series of $f(x)$ is $f(0) + x \cdot f^{(1)}(0) + x^2 \cdot \frac{f^{(2)}(0)}{2!} + .. + x^n \cdot \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} + .. $

But $f(x)$ and its derivatives isn't defined at $x=0$ so how do we find the maclaurin series of $f(x)$?

Comment: Note the 1 in the argument of the log...

Comment: The derivative $$\dfrac{d}{dx}F(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}.$$
So $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}.$

Comment: Woops! My bad. Went a bit too fast. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Have a nice day!